# Project with Google APi with self user auth

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I was able to create a project to connect an app to google data, for a specific account (followed [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey))

But now I would like that each customer log in hisself to his account and manage his data.

I can' t create project in the Google API Console for each customer, my app needs to read auth from each user who will use my app and "auto" create auth to read google contact data of the logged user.

Is possible?

Could you suggest me articles about how to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do exactly what OAuth 2.0 (see the page you linked to) gives you: authenticating users. This differs from using an API key, which is only authorizing your project and has nothing to do with a user's credentials.

OAuth 2.0 combines a Client ID (associated with your Google Developers Console project) and a user's login (specific to the user who is accessing your app/site) to give you an authorization token. This token will let your app act on behalf of that user when calling that API. Just make sure to request the necessary scopes as part of the OAuth 2.0 authorization prompt given to the user.

How to give this prompt varies by environment, but many common options are listed on [that link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Note that you always use the same Client ID, so you only need one Google Developers Console project, but you are given a unique token specific to that user's login when they authorize your app, so this lets you act as any user which grants your app access to their account.